# How to get current center point when I move view using CGAffineTransformTranslate?

Tags: iphone, transform, frame, cgaffinetransform, nslog

I move a view using `CGAffineTransformTranslate`, when I use `NSlog: view.center.x`, this value is not changes when I move? But I `NSlog: view.frame.orgin.x`, this current value always changes when I move! So, how to get current value center when I move?

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to get the center of the frame. This can be accomplished fairly easily.

Define a function like this:

```
CGPoint CGRectCenter(CGRect rect)
{
    return CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
}
```

And then you can get the center of your view with:

```
CGRectCenter(view.frame);
```

EDIT:

I just looked at the [documentation for `frame` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5), and it says the value of `frame` is undefined if a transform has been applied. You might be better using `view.layer.frame`, as the documentation for CALayer doesn't carry the same warning. I suspect however, that the UIView method is just calling the CALayer one, so you might be ok.